# Is there a computationally efficient way to store values smaller than a byte in multidimensional arrays in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

My current project involves working with arrays of 5+ dimensions, but the individual elements of the array do not need to have 256 possible values.  I was wondering if I could save on memory space by using a custom data type with, for example, only 4 or 6 bits to represent the value of an element, and if these memory savings would come at some significant performance cost.

Comment: Take a look at `std::bitset`.

Comment: There is also the bit-fields feature built in to C and C++, which might be useful here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Comment: @Jeremy Bit-fields are hardly "computationally efficient", and highly unportable.

Comment: @NeilButterworth computationally efficient is relative, and bit fields roughly as portable as integers are (that is, you need proper serialisation when trying to communicate with other machines with different representations).

Comment: @NeilButterworth do you have reason to believe that bitfields are less efficient than the other available methods for accomplishing the same task?  (AFAIK the efficiency hit occurs when you start doing bit-shift/mask operations, and pretty much any squeeze-values-into-fewer-bits-than-one-byte solution is going to have invoke those, whether it's the programmer writing the logic explicitly or the STL or the compiler generating code behind the scenes to do it).  As for portability, the bitfield code will compile and run correctly on any compliant C or C++ compiler, will it not?

Comment: @Jeremy No, I don't thionk they are less efficient - I think this is not an approach you want to take if computational efficiency is an issue. And if you believe bitfields are portable, I have a bridge to sell you.

Comment: As an addendum, to quote Brian Kernighan, in "The Practice of Programming" - "Don't use C or C++ bitfields; they are highly  non - portable and  tend to  generate  voluminous and inefficient code"

Comment: @Neilbutterworth I do not think that binary portability is a main OPs issue. And I think you do not understand when they can be not portable. When used as integers, not to occupy exactly the same bits on every hardware, they are 100% portable. Most modern processors and uCs even have special instructions for the bitfields

Comment: @NeilButterworth- I must admit I get tired of seeing religious "don't use XYZ" statements, since there are almost always situations where XYZ is genuinely useful. There are non-portable usages of `int` too (e.g. range of representable values is implementation-defined) but not many folks suggest avoiding `int` because of that. Bitfields are a valid option for this question but a range of portability concerns need to be considered before deciding to use them. "Computation efficiency" is also relative- what's acceptable depends on requirements, compiler quality of implementation, etc etc.

Comment: The real problem with bitfields in this case is neither portability nor (in)efficiency but rather the fact that C doesn't have bitfield arrays. Bitfields can only be members of a `struct`. That makes them difficult to use to compress arrays; there is no simple way to write "the bitfield with index i". But in general I agree with @peter: there are applications for bitfields and in those cases they're a lot less ugly than macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multidimensional arrays in C are really basically arrays of arrays.
(It can't be any other way as RAM is inherently linear).
You can emulate them on linear arrays in terms of pointer arithmetic:

```
#undef NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
    typedef uint32_t TYPE;
    enum{A=3,B=4,C=5};
    TYPE a[A][B][C];

    assert((char*)&a[1][2][3] == ((char*)&a) + \
          3*sizeof(TYPE) + 2 *C*sizeof(TYPE) + 1 *B*C*sizeof(TYPE));
}
```

Computers don't let you address sub-char types but it's not difficult to imagine a sub-char type.

The above char offset calculation for addressing a[1][2][3] could be rewriten like

```
char_ix = (3*sizeof(TYPE)*CHAR_BIT + 2 *C*sizeof(TYPE)*CHAR_BIT + 1 *B*C*sizeof(TYPE)*CHAR_BIT)/CHAR_BIT;
```

and if instead of chars (8-bits) you wanted to address e.g., 4-bits, you'd change it to

```
char_ix_of_4_bit = 
     (3*sizeof(TYPE)*CHAR_BIT/2 + 
      2 *C*sizeof(TYPE)*CHAR_BIT/2 + 
      1 *B*C*sizeof(TYPE)*CHAR_BIT/2) \
     / CHAR_BIT; //2 4-bits per octet

char_ix_of_4_bit_remainder = 
     (3*sizeof(TYPE)*CHAR_BIT/2 + 
      2 *C*sizeof(TYPE)*CHAR_BIT/2 + 
      1 *B*C*sizeof(TYPE)*CHAR_BIT/2) \
     % CHAR_BIT; //2 4-bits per octet
```

The 4 bit value at the destination would then be

```
((unsigned char*)&a)[char_ix_of_4_bit] >> (4*char_ix_of_4_bit_remainder)
```

Similar for other bit groups.

In short, you can think of multidimensional bit arrays, reimagine them as linear bit arrays and then use regular indexing and bit shifting
to address the appropriate bit group or individual bits (IIRC, C++'s `std::bitset`/`std::vector<bool>` hide the last part under bit indexing
with an overloaded [] operator, but it's not hard to do it manually (which is what you'll need to do in pure C anyway, as pure C doesn't have operator overloading).

Bit ops are said to be slower and generate larger code than operations with whole types, but this might be well be offset by better cache locality, which using sub-char bit arrays might buy you depending on your data (you'd better have lots of data if you're attempting to do this).

Comment: There's the eternal trade-off between space and speed here.

Comment: I recommend `(unsigned char*)` instead of `(char*)` to avoid the usual sign shifting issues.